# Print Devenagari ( देवनागरि ) Unicode in PDF in Laravel 4 using barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Tags: unicode, laravel-4, dompdf

I am trying to convert HTML content into PDF in Laravel 4. I am using [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf) package. The content has some Nepali Characters (Devnagari font). I am not able to display these unicode characters in the PDF. If I view it as an HTML view, it works fine. The PDF just ignores the unicode characters.

I tried using Helvetica font as suggested in most solutions online.

```
body {
font-family: 'Helvetica'
}
```

It recognizes the character but can't render it. I get boxes where the character are supposed to be.

I have tried loading external fonts that supports the Nepali Unicode. But it either doesn't render the unicode characters or the execution time exceeds or Laravel Shows error to the URL path of the font.

Comment: Why you still using Laravel 4?

Comment: Client requirment

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'PREETI';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url('{{ asset('/frontend/fonts/PREETI.TTF') }}') format('truetype');
    }
    body {
        font-family:  PREETI,DejaVu Sans, sans-serif ,Helvetica!important;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
</style>
```